# How to animate a panel to enroll over a MapView?

Tags: android, layout, animation

I've got a MapView within a RelativeLayout on the map at the top of the screen I want to display a panel with some text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >   
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="@string/google_maps_api_key"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/venue_panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/venue_panel_background" 
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >

        <TextView                        
            android:id="@+id/venue_panel_info_line"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/venue_panel_text" 
            android:text="Searching ..."
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"   
            android:visibility="visible"         
            />      
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The panel should be animated in such a way that is enrolls from top till it is large enough that the text within the panel is visible.

Unfortunately I'm very new to animations. How could I realize such an animation?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/) is good article on how to use `FrameLayout` to implement panels over `mapview`

Recently Wunderlist opened their implementation of sliding panel. You can find it [here](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib)